# how to connect to psql using password on kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, psql

I want to connect to psql using password on `kubectl exec` command on kubernetes like

```
kubectl exec -it postgres -- bash \`psql -h $IP -U admin --password password -p $PORT dbname\`
```

I tried to command

```
kubectl exec -it $podid -- bash \`psql -h $IP -U admin --password -p $PORT postgresdb\`
```

and

```
kubectl exec -it $podid -- bash -c "psql -- dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@$ip:$port/postgresdb -c 'INSERT INTO public."user" (user_id,user_pw,user_nm,email,phone,is_admin) VALUES ('admin','admin','admin','admin@admin.com',NULL,true);'"
```

but these command did not work.

How can I connect to psql using kubernetes commands and password?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try
`kubectl exec -it <postgresspod-name> bash or sh`
when you inside the container you can just do
`PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host or service name or localhost> -U <username> <dbname>`

another option is
`` kubectl exec -it postgres -- bash \`PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host or service name or localhost> -U <username> <dbname>\` ``

Comment: the first line works for me. But as soon as I try the second solution in powershell, I get `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'U' in -U`. It looks like despite the escapes and backticks, kubectl tries to evaluate it instead of passing it on to bash.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me (command PGPASSWORD=<...> not found).

This worked :

```
kubectl  exec -ti postgres -- env PGPASSWORD=$PASSWD psql psql -h <host> -U <username> <dbname>
```

Comment: man saved my day thanks! couldn't get how to pass password without bash -c

Answer (score 1):

As you asking only for command I assume you have all Deployments, Services, etc.

Please execute command below:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti <postgresspod-name> -- psql -h <node/host IP> -U postgresadmin --password -p <port> postgresdb
Password for user postgresadmin:
```

After you will type password you will be connected to Postgres

Answer (score 1):

For me only this works

```
kubectl exec postgres-postgresql-0 -n nte -- sh -c 'PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U "postgres" -d "database_name" -c "select * from table_name"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing arg `--env "PGPASSWORD=$POSTRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD"` works like a charm

```bash
kubectl run psql-client --rm -ti --restart=Never --namespace default --image bitnami/postgresql --env "PGPASSWORD=$POSTRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD" -- psql --port=5432 --dbname=postgres --username=$POSTRESQL_ADMIN_USERNAME --set=sslmode=require --host=$POSTRESQL_HOST -w
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this way :

```
kubectl exec -i <plsql podname> -- psql -h <host or service name or localhost> -u <username> -p<password>
```

Comment: this not work.
"-p" option means port number.. not password